# suggestcompletion endpoint doesn't respect locale parameter

Tags: foursquare

I'm working with the venues/suggestcompletion endpoint, and I've noticed that it does not respect the locale parameter when returning locations. It seems to translate category names though.

Example:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/suggestcompletion?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&locale=en&v=20141204&m=foursquare&ll=35.6894875,139.69170639999993&limit=5&query=jiro

Returns:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"response":{"minivenues":[{"id":"4b0587a0f964a5205e9d22e3","name":"Live Music JIROKICHI","location":{"address":"高円寺北2-3-4","crossStreet":"高円寺ビル B1F","city":"杉並区","state":"東京都","postalCode":"166-0002","country":"JP","lat":35.70566356501932,"lng":139.65131118893623,"distance":4071},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1e7931735","name":"Jazz Club","pluralName":"Jazz Clubs","shortName":"Jazz Club","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/arts_entertainment\/musicvenue_jazzclub_","suffix":".png"}},{"id":"4d4b7104d754a06370d81259","name":"Arts & Entertainment","pluralName":"Arts & Entertainment","shortName":"Arts & Entertainment","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/arts_entertainment\/default_","suffix":".png"}},{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1e5931735","name":"Music Venue","pluralName":"Music Venues","shortName":"Music Venue","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/arts_entertainment\/musicvenue_","suffix":".png"}},{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1e9931735","name":"Rock Club","pluralName":"Rock Clubs","shortName":"Rock Club","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/arts_entertainment\/musicvenue_rockclub_","suffix":".png"}}]},{"id":"4df88a6f1495b7db1b0ec39b","name":"とんこつ大盛野菜ラーメン JIRORAMO","location":{"address":"相武台1-4507","crossStreet":"相武台ビル１Ｆ","city":"座間市","state":"神奈川県","postalCode":"","country":"JP","lat":35.49931385465121,"lng":139.40754349524184,"distance":33313},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1d1941735","name":"Ramen \/ Noodle House","pluralName":"Ramen \/ Noodle House","shortName":"Ramen \/ Noodles","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/ramen_","suffix":".png"}},{"id":"4d4b7105d754a06374d81259","name":"Food","pluralName":"Food","shortName":"Food","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/default_","suffix":".png"}}]},{"id":"4df982cad4c064db03a97ae1","name":"Betterabe Bistro Jiro","location":{"address":"富ヶ谷1-2-8","crossStreet":"","city":"渋谷区","state":"東京都","postalCode":"","country":"JP","lat":35.668034699164494,"lng":139.69092056158243,"distance":2389},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d110941735","name":"Italian Restaurant","pluralName":"Italian Restaurants","shortName":"Italian","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/italian_","suffix":".png"}},{"id":"4d4b7105d754a06374d81259","name":"Food","pluralName":"Food","shortName":"Food","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/default_","suffix":".png"}},{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d10c941735","name":"French Restaurant","pluralName":"French Restaurants","shortName":"French","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/french_","suffix":".png"}}]},{"id":"4b76c40ff964a520975d2ee3","name":"Jiro's Bar","location":{"address":"両国3-26-6","crossStreet":"駅前ストリート","city":"東京","state":"","postalCode":"","country":"JP","lat":35.695693,"lng":139.793755,"distance":9251},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d116941735","name":"Bar","pluralName":"Bars","shortName":"Bar","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/nightlife\/pub_","suffix":".png"}},{"id":"4d4b7105d754a06376d81259","name":"Nightlife Spot","pluralName":"Nightlife Spots","shortName":"Nightlife","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/nightlife\/default_","suffix":".png"}}]},{"id":"530b393b498eedd60dc1375b","name":"BAR JIROISE","location":{"address":"","crossStreet":"","city":"","state":"","postalCode":"","country":"JP","lat":35.658016204833984,"lng":139.69776916503906,"distance":3545},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d116941735","name":"Bar","pluralName":"Bars","shortName":"Bar","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/nightlife\/pub_","suffix":".png"}},{"id":"4d4b7105d754a06376d81259","name":"Nightlife Spot","pluralName":"Nightlife Spots","shortName":"Nightlife","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/nightlife\/default_","suffix":".png"}}]}]}}
```

Notice that the city names are in Japanese, yet I did specify en as the locale.

The venues/search endpoint returns city names in English, as expected.

Is this by design or a bug?